# Finding a directory in a Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I find a particular directory in a terminal window in Linux? I think it involves using grep, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: removing `find-in-files` tag since you are locating a directory, no file-content-search is implied.

Comment: What do you know about the directory that would allow you to find it?

Comment: you have to provide at least some search criteria, "particular" is a bit vague. one can find items on the disc based upon names, relation ships, sizes, content, etc etc.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Would you be looking for something like this?

```
find . -type d | grep DIRNAME
```

Comment: what's wrong with `find . -name DIRNAME -type d`?

Comment: @honk, Nothing `:-)` -- the OP seems to like `grep`; and we all like variety

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: Five years later I did notice the answer in the comment was slower to process than the original answer. Maybe a glitch. Anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 34):

If you want to find a particular directory that might be anywhere on your computer, the following will work, but it might take a while.

```
find / -name DIRNAME -type d
```

Comment: And, if you want to `find` within the working directory -- replace '`/`' with '`.`' -- could get quicker.

Answer (score 4):

If you have it installed, `locate` is designed for this. 
[Google "man locate"](http://www.google.com/search?q=man+locate)

Comment: Though locate won't provide you real-time results, but instead returns the results it gathered while updatedb was last run. If the filesystem doesn't change much, then it isn't a real problem and locate is very fast.

Comment: -1 Locate is designed to find files, not directories. Or is there an option I am not aware of?

Comment: locate works just fine for directories.